# How to get 0 to display instead of #DIV/0 in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I am a novice at Excel and need some help with a formula.  I have a set of cells that are the sum of a formula. They are based on information from month to month. At times this can be zero. I want to average them out and am using this formula =AVERAGE(IF(F17:Q17<>0, F17:Q17,"")). That works fine. But, I want it to display 0 if there are no values other than 0, instead it shows #DIV/0! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

a simple way is to =if(sum(F17:Q17)=0,0,average(if(F17:Q17<>0,F17:q17,""))) there's also the 'averageifs' statement you should be using to make life simpler.

Answer (score 2):

the `IFERROR` wrapper will take care of that problem. It's am optimized version of `IF(ISERROR(formula)....`

Your formula would then be

```
=IFERRROR(AVERAGE(IF(F17:Q17<>0, F17:Q17,"")),0)
```

note that this will hide all errors, so make sure your formulas work as expected first, before putting the `IFERROR` around them.